# How to get a facebook token that does not expire or it does how to not have users reauth

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

I have a dashboard where users click a button and is redirected to Facebook where they allow me to access ad reports.  It works.  I get an access token and make another request to get the long access token which expires every 60 days.

I was mistakenly under the impression that as long as the access token was not expired e.g. 3 days prior to expiration, I would be able to extend for another 60 days.  No such luck. I try and get a new long-lived access token the expiration is the same.

How do I get a token where my users do not have to reauth every 60 days?  I cant find the docs.

This [post](https://drgabrielharris.medium.com/python-how-making-facebook-api-calls-using-facebook-sdk-ea18bec973c8) claims to be able to get a permanent access token but I don't know how to modify it for a client.

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=user_long_token, version="3.0")
pages_data = graph.get_object("/me/accounts")

permanent_page_token = pages_data["data"][0]["access_token"]
page_id = pages_data["data"][0]["id"]
```

DO I modify /me/accounts?  If so how for a client? I can pass the user_long_token but the response I get is:

```
 print(pages_data)
 {'data': []}
```

I assume I have to replace /me/accounts with something else.  All I have in an account id, an access token, and long access token.

Utterly confused.  Thanks

Comment: The link is how to get Permanent Page Access Token. You can't get Permanent User Acess Tokens.

Comment: Then how do I get a permanent access token without the user having to reauth every 60 days?

Comment: You can't. There is no way to get a user access token that is permanent.

Comment: Then a user has to refresh permissions every 60 days?  I make api calls once an hour.  If this is the case I am ok with that now what to know if there is a way to extend token for another 60 days with a currently active token.  I tried but did not work.

Comment: No there is no way to extend the token without user interaction

Comment: _"DO I modify /me/accounts?"_ - no, `/me` automatically resolves to whom-/whatever the token belongs to. With a user token, this will resolve to the corresponding user account, and with a page token, to that page.